# Refering to Table cell in Macro

Tags: vba, excel

***So, I am relatively new to VBA and Programming as a whole,***

I know in Excel Formulae, Rather than refer directly to a Cell **($B$27**) you can refer to the Column name instead, **(@[Condition]).**

Now I am aware that this only works on "linear" tables, the formulae will only work on and affect the row its in, but for the table i am working on this is fine.

***My question is, is there a way to refer to this inside VBA?***

I am trying to create a function that takes the value of a "Condition" Cell and if this is "Other" it will open a custom User form with 3 buttons that allow the user to select the reason why the Condition is "other"

Depending on the button click, the Value of another Cell in the same table (Works Completed) will be changed to what ever the reason they click.

(E.G, user clicks "To be Repaired",  the value of "Works Complete"  will be changed to "For Repairs"

This currently only works when referred to a Cell directly ($B$27)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a question, concerning the translation of a manual action in Excel to VBA the best answer is:

*Start the macro recorder, do the manual action and check yourself.*

This is a sample of a recorded macro, selecting `Table1`, `Column3`:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column3]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Testing"
    Range("C2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: To refer to parts of a table using VBA, see the website:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: Thanks, this greatly improves my understanding of certain coding within VBA,

However this seems to have the same problem where everytime the macro is ran, it will always affect the same cell no matter what is selected, similar to if  you were to put (C1) in VBA, Rather than:
 
Table1[[#Headers],[Column3]]